# Why do my API routes send back the index.html file when deployed? (Single express app serving create-react-app build file)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, express, create-react-app

I am working on a create-react-app. During development I had the backend server running on on a proxy configured in the package.json and it worked great. Then I learned that this proxy feature was only for development and not for production. After looking around I found that a simple solution for production is to serve the build folder from the express server along with all the API routes. This method is outlined in the create-react-app docs here: **https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/**

Using this method (with some tweaks and changes) the app works perfectly when running on localhost. However when I deploy to production (using firebase) the app renders correctly but API routes don't work. The routes seem to be sending back the index.html file of the create-react-app build instead of data.

Here are the basics of my express server:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


//API routes...

app.post('/api/test', async (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world!")
});

//Serving the front end...

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Running on port 3000'));
```

Here is my API call in the front end using fetch:

```
handleTest = async () => {
    return fetch('/api/test', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          foo: "bar",
        }),
      });
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            console.log(response.text())
        });
};
```

Here is the response I get when I hit '/api/test' while deployed to the live site:

```
Response {type: 'basic', url: 'https://example.com/api/test', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
```

Digging deeper into the response, it seems to be HTML, and appears to be the index.js file of my build:

```
Promise {<pending>}[[Prototype]]: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseResult]]: "<!doctype html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon\" ... "
```

Any idea why this API call would work when running on localhost but not work when deployed on firebase? Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: What do you mean "deployed to Firebase"? If you mean to Firebase Hosting, you shouldn't be using Express at all and if you mean to Cloud Functions for Firebase, you shouldn't be using Express with `listen()`, instead returning the `app` object to be handled by the Cloud Function. In both cases, you should be using [`firebase emulators:start`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) to test locally.

Comment: ... documentation here ~ https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#use_a_web_framework

Comment: I am using Firebase Hosting. So I need to use Cloud Functions instead of express? Thanks for the info, I will do some research on this.

Answer (score 0):

`Response.text()`,  Returns a promise that resolves with a text representation of the response body. You're indeed printing promise and that is correct behaviour. more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

```
handleTest = async () => {
return fetch('/api/test', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      fu: "bar",
    }),
  })
.then(response => response.text())
.then((text) => {
  console.log(text)
})
};
```

Alternatively (as you're in an async method) not tested:

```
handleTest = async () => {
return fetch('/api/test', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      fu: "bar",
    }),
  })
.then(response =>  {
        let res = await response.text();
        console.log(res);
    })

};
```

Comment: also handletest will also return a promise as its an async function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is more asking why this route returns HTML when it is deployed, but it works when running locally. I appreciate your help!